# Webpack slow build performance with large ES6 module

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, webpack

For localization in my React project I am using an auto-generated ES6 module that looks like this:

```
var Resources = new Array();
Resources['en-US']={};
Resources['en-US'].hello = 'Hello';
Resources['en-US'].welcome = 'Welcome';

.. snip ...

Resources['sv-SE']={};
Resources['sv-SE'].hello = 'Hej';
Resources['sv-SE'].welcome = 'Välkommen';

export default Resources;
```

The Resources array contains approx 2500 items.

In my React components I use the Resource module like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Resources from '../Assets/Resources';

var Test = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        culture: React.PropTypes.string
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>{Resources[this.props.culture].hello</div>
        );
    }    
});

export default Test;
```

The problem is when I use Webpack for bundling the project. The build time is around 78 seconds (78000ms), incremental builds are fast though (around 400ms).

If I strip the Resources array to a much smaller amount of items (for example 10 items) the build time goes down to 7 seconds (7000ms) which seems much more reasonable.

Does anyone have any idea how to speed up the build time?

Comment: keep resources as json file? so that webpack does not have to process it as javascript?

Comment: why is resources an array?

Comment: @maioman, the array solution is so that I can call the localization by using Resources['en-US'].hello for example. Do you have any better implementation of the Resources module so that I can still fetch the proper localization by using the same syntax (or a syntax that ressembles)?

Comment: I'd use an object (map) , an array is a specialized kind of object for indexed property and I don't see the need for it in your example. This is just a general advice probably this has nothing to do with the performance issue.

Comment: @AdamWolski thank you for your suggestion! Changing my resources as a json and including a json loader solved the problem of slow build times. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can give you credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to keep the resource module as json file (if the data does not require any sort of computing done by JavaScript) and use appropriate loader (`json-loader`) .

By doing that, webpack won't process the file as JS thus the build time should be quicker.